# how can i search multiple keywords in laravel .?

Tags: laravel, search, keyword

This is my controller

```
 $term = $request->get('q');

 // return $request->q;

 $products = Post::whereHas('user', function($query) use($term) {
     $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
 })->orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->get();
 return view('pages.search', compact('products','users'));
```

This is working good for single keyword search. But I want to use it for multiple keywords. Like laravel php etc. Please guide me when I search multiple values like abc php laravel or anything then it should work. If tags exists in different column like php is present in 1st column and laravel is in next column when I search php laravel then it should show me both column values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably a better way to do this, like using CloudSearch/Algolia, but this is a solution that has worked for us:

```
// Split the terms by word.
$terms = explode(" ", request('q'));

$products = Post::query()
    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) use ($terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            // Loop over the terms and do a search for each.
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        }
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($terms) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $query->where('tags', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        }
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin There is no need to re-assign query, or return it. Its a reference. Additionally it depends on your use-case, but I thought Laravel had removed the ability to do a `orWhere` when you hadn't originally done a `where`.

Comment: I've just tested it and it doesn't work. You don't need to re-assign query, but you can't just use `->where` in the loop or the closure as you do. So, you need to re-assign `$posts` as I've shown in my code and build a bunch of `orWhere` and for `whereHas()` part it should be one `where` and a bunch of `orWhere()`.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin You've changed your code since my last comment to remove the bit you were talking about in your initial comment that you have also deleted. The code shown in my answer should work without issue, and does in one of our production sites.

Comment: Yes, I've tested both my code and yours and edited by code, after that I've added the previous comment. Your code doesn't work, I've tested it.

Comment: You were right about re-assigning `$query->where`, but OP will still need to re-assign `$posts` (or whatever the variable is) after he'll add multiple `orWhere`.

Comment: also giving the same result as i want . but just for one column tags . but this is good

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon This code just can't work for you because of two reasons I've described.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin this code work for one column only . i mean when i enters the tag keywords in search then it find a column tag and search code . but if both kewords is present there in tag column then its working but if one is persent and 2nd one is not there then its show nothing . . but its working for if two or more keywords are correct  .

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon that's because this code uses `AND` for both User and Post models and you need `OR`

Comment: i just add orwhere in last foreach loop now its working good . user name with post ' tag

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon Glad I could help, feel free to accept this answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon even if you'll change `where` to `orWhere` in the last loop, it will not work because for User model it will still use `AND` instead of `OR`. I've explained everything in my answer an hour ago.

Comment: yes this is AND @AlexeyMezenin but how can i change it to or . ur code is giving error . can u please tell me ur code . because that code that u have posted giving me some error . 
 public function searchme(Request $request){
  $term = $request->get('q');
$products = Post::whereHas('user', function($query) use($term) {
          $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
           ->orwhere('email', 'like', '%'.$term.'%');
      })->orWhere('tags','LIKE','%'.$term.'%')->get();
      return view('pages.search', compact('products','users'));
} this is complete function of search

Comment: this code showing me result only first parameter of tag when i used second tag and dont use first tag value this it show nothing

Answer (score 2):

I spent lots of time on this over the past couple days, and here is my solution. It's similar to these other ones but different, so it may be of value for someone one day:

I have a Vue component that makes a GET request, so `$request->get('searchTerms')` comes from `<input name="searchTerms">` in the HTML form submit.

I wanted to allow to user to control which fields were going to be searched, so that's why `$search_terms` is an array of columns to search.

I wanted it so if the user searched for "McDonalds 604" that it would filter the list of records and show two different matches for that search. One matching "McDonalds" for `business_name` and one matching "604" for the area code of the `phone_number`. This would ensure the user would get everything related in case they only knew some fragments.

> **The goal** was to iterate over the search terms and also to iterate over the search fields (columns) with a generic formula that could be applied from any number of search terms and columns, dynamic at runtime.

```
        $search_fields = ['project_name', 'business_name', 'phone_number'];
        $search_terms = explode(' ', $request->get('searchTerms'));

        $query = Campaign::query();
        foreach ($search_terms as $term) {
            $query->orWhere(function ($query) use ($search_fields, $term) {

                foreach ($search_fields as $field) {
                    $query->orWhere($field, 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%');
                }
            });
        }
        $filtered = $query->get();
```

I would recommend reading through the query docs for Laravel because it will give you better intuition about this task: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

In the above code, we are using `parameter grouping` and it changes the characteristics of the algorithm if you use `where` vs. `orWhere`.

**Bonus Factoids**

I also highly recommend testing your SQL statements using `$query->toSql()` and `$query->getBindings()`. You can put those in place of `$query->get()` to see what the SQL statement it is generating will look like and what the parameter bindings are. `getBindings()` will show you what the values of the `?` are in `toSql()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare the `$terms` array first, then just iterate over it and add `orWhere()` clauses.

I've just tested it and for `whereHas()` closure you need to use `where()` for the first term and `orWhere()`for the rest of it to make it work:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('user', function($q) use($terms) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term .'%');

        foreach (array_slice($terms, 1) as $term) {
            $q->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $term .'%');
        }
    });

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $posts->orWhere('tags', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
}

$posts = $posts->get();
```

If you'll decide to use `=` instead of `like`, just use `whereIn()` instead of building query with a bunch of `orWhere()`.